# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING when trying to access the Salesforce API with beatbox

Tags: python, api, salesforce, beatbox

I am using [`beatbox`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beatbox/32.1) to access the SOAP API of Salesforce. More specifically, I am trying to convert a `Lead` using `convertLead` like so

```
# Assuming soap_client is a PythonClient already logged in and
# lead is a Lead object.

response = soap_client.convertLead({
    'leadId': lead.pk,
    'convertedStatus': "Qualified - converted",
})
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_convertlead.htm) this endpoint should not need any more parameter than `leadId` and `convertedStatus`, however the response contains the following error message

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [Company_Name__c]: [Company_Name__c] (System
>   Code)UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION00Qg0000003Er0pEACfalse

It is good to mention that `lead` (the `Lead` object to be converted) actually contains a non empty `Company` field.

Any idea of what could cause this error message? I tried to specifically add a `companyName` field to the API call but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your explanation you are getting the error of Required fields are missing (Company_Name__c) and you tried to assign the value to this "companyName" field, But you are getting error for custom field not **standard salesforce field.**

So i think when you are converting it, then may be some account / contact custom field is required [Required fields are missing: [Company_Name__c]]. So you need to assign value of that field explicitly in your code.

If you want to map the custom field then please check below link :

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_mapleads.htm&language=en

Otherwise if you did not want to check required field on lead conversion then you can disable that using following steps : 
1. Login to your salesforce org.
2. Setup
3. Customize
4. Leads 
5. Settings
6. Edit and uncheck the "Require Validation for Converted Leads".